# Prepopulating values for new users

Tags: apex, force.com

When we go to create a new user by going to setup-->users and  clicking on the standard button new user. we want to prepoulate a bunch of values. is there a strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the standard salesforce usage the above task Is not possible and what @sfdcfox said is right.

But we can achieve this with the help of Jquery/JavaScript.

This requires the 2 steps to achieve the task:-

In the javascript u just need to access the element using getElementbyID. Once u have this element add its values that you want to display.

Now second thing from where to add this javascript to a users page.

Create a new custom HTMl sidebar component and add the java script in that component. Make sure u use Internet explorer only while saving the javascript.

Add this component on the home page layout and assign this layout to the current profile u are having.

Next time when u access the user creation page the field values will be populated.

This is very high level design that I have given you let me know if u are interested in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields for Users can have default values. Standard fields for User cannot have default values. You can also set values via triggers in case the value was left blank. You cannot, however, have these values appear when the New button is clicked; they can be programmed to appear when the value was left blank. Of course, that won't work for required standard fields, for which case you cannot use a trigger nor supply a default value.

Comment: Yea, that's pretty much what i thought... i want the values prepopulated when the user clicks the button...